# How would I count null values but still specify to count in the history/loan tables

Tags: sql, oracle

My problem is

- For each member (using both member ID, last name, and first name), list the number of books
  he/she has currently checked out, and the number of books he/she checked out in the past.
- If a person
  checked out the same book multiple times, it will be counted multiple times.
- Zero count should also be
  listed as 0.

Naturally I took the approach to `count(history.bookID)` but while it displayed the right amount of books per member, it did not count null values. Considering this I attempted to do an outer join but as I cant specify `history.bookID` the function counts 7 for all.

Is there a way to count the number of instances in a relation while tagging on null values for anything not matched?

My tables are:

```
  drop table history;
     drop table currentloan;
     drop table member;
     drop table book;

 /*
    creates table with 6 variables
    assigns one primary key
    uses different data types for different cases
 */  

create table Book
(bookID             number(12) Primary Key,
 ISBN               number(13),
 title              varchar(50),
 author             varchar(20),
 publish_year       number(4),
 category           char(11));

 /*
    Inserts tuples with matching variables 
    uses different book categories for testing purposes  
 */ 

insert into Book values('7839494', '9780143122784', 'Guitar Zero', 'Gary Marcus', '2012', 'non-fiction');
insert into Book values('7839495', '9780143122784', 'Guitar Zero', 'Gary Marcus', '2012', 'non-fiction');
insert into Book values('7839496', '9780143122784', 'Guitar Zero', 'Gary Marcus', '2012', 'non-fiction');
insert into Book values('1405904', '9780071812436', 'Oracle Database 12c PL/SQL Programming', 'Michael McLaughlin', '2014', 'reference');
insert into Book values('9890304', '9781449343033', 'Oracle Essentials: Oracle Database 12c', 'Rick Greenwald', '2013', 'reference');
insert into Book values('1893409', '9781598635034', 'Music Theory for Computer Musicians', 'Gary Marcus', '2008', 'non-fiction');
insert into Book values('3848598', '9781119247791', 'Java All-in-One For Dummies', 'Doug Lowe', '2017', 'non-fiction');
insert into Book values('3848599', '9781119247791', 'Java All-in-One For Dummies', 'Doug Lowe', '2017', 'non-fiction');
insert into Book values('3049891', '9780679805274', 'Oh, the Places Youll Go', 'Dr. Seuss', '1990', 'Childrens');
insert into Book values('3049892', '9780679805274', 'Oh, the Places Youll Go', 'Dr. Seuss', '1990', 'Childrens');
insert into Book values('9839209', '9780072465631', 'Database Management Systems', 'Raghu Ramakrishnan', '2008', 'reference');
insert into Book values('3234567', '9780316605106', 'Cirque du Freak: A Living Nightmare', 'Darren Shan', '2002', 'fiction');
insert into Book values('3234568', '9780316605106', 'Cirque du Freak: A Living Nightmare', 'Darren Shan', '2002', 'fiction');
insert into Book values('3234569', '9780316605106', 'Cirque du Freak: A Living Nightmare', 'Darren Shan', '2002', 'fiction');
insert into Book values('3234570', '9780316605106', 'Cirque du Freak: A Living Nightmare', 'Darren Shan', '2002', 'fiction');
insert into Book values('1239480', '9781421539645', 'DeathNote Black Edition Vol. 1', 'Tsugumi Ohba', '2010', 'fiction');
insert into Book values('5467878', '9780877798095', 'Merriam_Websters Collegiate Dictionary', 'Merriam_Webster', '2003', 'reference');
insert into Book values('5467879', '9780877798095', 'Merriam_Websters Collegiate Dictionary', 'Merriam_Webster', '2003', 'reference');
insert into Book values('8930982', '9780073523323', 'Database Systems Concepts', 'Abraham Silberschatz', '2010', 'reference');
insert into Book values('7893098', '9780903923498', 'Database Design', 'Qin Ding', '2018', 'reference');
insert into Book values('3094098', '9780691162768', 'The Future of the Brain: Essays by the World's Leading Neuroscientists', 'Gary Marcus', '2014', 'reference');

commit;

 /*
    Creates member table with 6 variables 
    assigns one primary key 
    uses not null to ensure efficiency
  */ 
create table Member
(memberID            number(15) Primary Key,
 lastname            char(15),
 firstname           char(15) not null,
 address             varchar(30),
 phone_number        number(10),
 limit               number(3));


 /*
    Uses insert to fill member table with values 
    ensures values differ for testing  
*/

insert into Member values ('00986845', 'Guevara', 'Merlyn', '9705 hardwood ln', '9806369324', '5');
insert into Member values ('00425663', 'Courtney', 'Kacey', '1520 glengarry dr', '9848339522', '5');
insert into Member values ('00327889',  'Wells', 'Trey', '650 zack rd', '9802428333', '5');
insert into Member values ('00546283', 'Lopez', 'Manny', '123 Road st', '7046368300', '10');
insert into Member values ('00728432', 'Mondragon', 'Alpha', '6100 Raven peak dr', '7043028422', '5'); 
insert into Member values ('00345674', 'Jones', 'David', '4321 Rowan Way', '9803334564', '7');
insert into Member values ('00456742', 'Smith', 'John', '3456 Circle Pl', '7043239098', '8');
commit;


  /*    Generates table to track books checked out 
        Initializes 4 different variables
 */
create table CurrentLoan
( memberID           number(15),
  bookID             number(12),
  loan_date          varchar(10),
  due_date           varchar(10),
  FOREIGN KEY(bookID) REFERENCES book(bookID),
  Foreign key(memberID) REFERENCES member(memberID));


 /*
    uses insert to add currently checked out books  
*/

insert into Currentloan values('00986845', '7839494', '09/28/2018', '12/28/2018');
insert into Currentloan values('00546283', '1405904', '08/12/2018', '11/12/2018');
insert into Currentloan values('00327889', '9839209', '09/05/2018', '12/05/2018');
insert into Currentloan values('00345674', '1239480', '08/04/2018', '10/12/2018');
insert into Currentloan values('00456742', '1893409', '07/04/2018', '10/04/2018');
insert into Currentloan values('00456742', '5467878', '07/05/2018', '10/05/2018');
insert into Currentloan values('00456742', '7839496', '07/05/2018', '10/05/2018');
insert into Currentloan values('00456742', '3848599', '07/05/2018', '10/05/2018');
insert into Currentloan values('00456742', '3049892', '07/05/2018', '10/05/2018');
insert into Currentloan values('00456742', '3234569', '07/05/2018', '10/05/2018');
insert into Currentloan Values('00986845', '3234568', '08/02/2018', '11/02/2018');
insert into Currentloan Values('00986845', '3049891', '08/02/2018', '11/02/2018');
insert into Currentloan Values('00986845', '3848598', '08/02/2018', '11/02/2018');
insert into Currentloan Values('00986845', '5467879', '08/02/2018', '11/02/2018');
insert into Currentloan Values('00986845', '3234570', '08/02/2018', '11/02/2018');
insert into Currentloan Values('00728432', '7893098', '10/28/2018', '01/28/2019');
insert into Currentloan Values('00728432', '8930982', '10/28/2018', '01/28/2019');
commit;


 /*     Generates table of books checked out in the past
     Initializes 4 variables 
    deterines primary and foreign keys
 */
create table History
(memberID            number(15),
 bookID              number(12),
 loan_date           varchar(10) Primary Key,
 return_date         varchar(10),
 Foreign Key(bookID) References book(bookID),
 Foreign Key(memberID) References member(memberID));
 /*
    uses insert to specify previously checked out books. 
 */
insert into History values ('00728432', '5467878', '02/08/2017', '04/05/2017');
insert into History values ('00986845', '3234567', '09/12/2017', '10/10/2017');
insert into History values ('00728432', '3848598', '07/14/2016', '09/04/2017');
insert into History values ('00986845', '1239480', '11/14/2016', '01/26/2017');
insert into History values ('00456742', '3234569', '07/05/2016', '09/02/2016');
insert into History values ('00327889', '7893098', '06/02/2016', '08/01/2016');
insert into History values ('00327889', '8930982', '06/01/2016', '08/01/2016');
commit;
```

My Query is:

```
 Select lastname,firstname, member.memberID, count(bookID)
    from member, book left outer join history
    group by lastname,firstname, member.memberID;
```

My output i get is:

```
LASTNAME        FIRSTNAME         MEMBERID COUNT(BOOKID)
--------------- --------------- ---------- -------------
Guevara         Merlyn              986845             7
Mondragon       Alpha               728432             7
Courtney        Kacey               425663             7
Wells           Trey                327889             7
Smith           John                456742             7
Lopez           Manny               546283             7
Jones           David               345674             7
```

I dont understand how to specify zero value while still counting each instance of the history table that matches the book or member table.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Questions which get the most attention here are _minimal_, meaning that they give the _least_ amount of information necessary to get the point across.  You have given 100+ lines of code, but your question is still unclear.  Please clarify your question.

Comment: You need to use `left join` with `history` and `currentloan` to get members with zero count.

Comment: please update the exact output what you want

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things wrong with your query:

1. It mixes explicit (ANSI-92) join syntax with Old Skool implicit cross join syntax. Don't mix styles.
2. It references `book` which it doesn't need to reference.
3. It doesn't reference `currentloan`, which it ought to reference.

A more correct solution would look like this:

```
Select member.lastname
       , member.firstname
       , member.memberID
       , nvl(curr.cnt,0) + nvl(hist.cnt, 0) as no_of_loans
from member
     left outer join ( select member_id, count(*) as cnt 
                       from history
                       group by member_id ) hist
     left outer join ( select member_id, count(*) as cnt 
                       from currentloan
                       group by member_id ) curr
order by member.memberID;
```